# Why Cypress is unable to determine if server is running?

Tags: docker, cypress

I've got an issue with running Cypress tests off a container.

In my `docker-compose` I've following services:  users, client, users-db, nginx and they're all running.

my `baseUrl` is set to `"http://nginx"` because I read somewhere that I need to reference
the service the server is running on which in my case is nginx.

I've tried also `"http://localhost"` and `"http://client"`

but when I run `docker run -it -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:4.11.0` I keep getting `Cypress could not verify that this server is running`

Any feedback that will lead to resolution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your cypress container is not part of the network used by the docker-compose containers.

Use `docker network ls` to see the list of available networks. There should be one named `<docker_compose.yml's directory>_default`.

You can then run a container in a specific network by specifying the `--network <network_name>` flag in `docker run`.

This container should be able to talk with the compose containers by using their service name as the hostname

Comment: Thank you so much ! This one was quite a headache for me. I noticed I was 1 vote away from my question being closed. Don't know why though.

Comment: So when running Cypress container outside of the network of other services I need to explicitly tell Cypress to which network to connect to to find the server. Nice !

Answer (score 0):

My issue is I have

```
network_mode: host
```

in my docker-compose file. Removing it made it pass.